AEM Creating Maven Project
I have AEM 6.5.0 (without any sp installed). I am practicing myself trying to install maven aem architype project into aem which leads to multiple dependency issues. Struggling with which architype to use for 6.5.0. Please guide me further. I dont have any SP for now and cant install any!
Trying to install a AEM maven architype project into aem 6.5.0, leads to multiple dependency issue. Cant install any SP for now. Please guide which architype to use for base 6.5.0 version.

You can try an older version of the archetype. The compatibility matrix is available here: https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype/blob/develop/VERSIONS.md
Here's the table, in case the link gets broken.



Archetype Version
AEM Version




7
6.0 or newer


8
6.0 or newer


9
6.0 or newer


10
6.0 or newer


11
6.2 or newer


12
6.3 or newer


14
6.4, 6.3 + SP2


15
6.4, 6.3 + SP2


16
6.4, 6.3 + SP2


13
6.4, 6.3 + SP2


17
6.4, 6.3 + SP2


18
6.5, 6.4, 6.3 + SP3


19
6.5, 6.4, 6.3 + SP3


20, 21, 22
6.5, 6.4, 6.3 + SP3


23
6.5, 6.4, 6.3 + SP3


24, 25, 26, 27
6.5.5, 6.4.8.1


28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44
6.5.7, AEM as a Cloud Service


45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51
6.5.17, AEM as a Cloud Service



Depending on what state your instance is in and what else has been installed, you may still run into dependency issues, but this should give you an easier start.
Keep in mind that you should ideally use the latest version of the archetype and keep AEM up to date. Using an older version is likely to cause more work in the future, as you prepare to upgrade.
If you have questions about specific dependency issues, raise them one by one. It's very difficult to say anything constructive about a broad issue like this.
